# Two functions in Matlab to approximate integral - not enough input arguments?

Tags: matlab

I want to write a function that approximates integrals with the trapezoidal rule.

I first defined a function in one file:

```
function[y] = integrand(x)
y = x*exp(-x^2); %This will be integrand I want to approximate
end
```

Then I wrote my function that approximates definite integrals with lower bound a and upper bound b (also in another file):

```
function [result] = trapez(integrand,a,b,k)

sum = 0;
h = (b-a)/k; %split up the interval in equidistant spaces

for j = 1:k
    x_j = a + j*h;  %this are the points in the interval
    sum = sum + ((x_j - x_(j-1))/2) * (integrand(x_(j-1)) + integrand(x_j));

end
result = sum
end
```

But when I want to call this function from the command window, using `result = trapez(integrand,0,1,10)` for example, I always get an error 'not enough input arguments'. I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous issues with your code:

- `x_(j-1)` is not defined, and is not really a valid Matlab syntax (assuming you want that to be a variable).
- By calling `trapez(integrand,0,1,10)` you're actually calling `integrand` function with no input arguments. If you want to pass a handle, use `@integrand` instead. But in this case there's no need to pass it at all.
- You should avoid variable names that coincide with Matlab functions, such as `sum`. This can easily lead to issues which are difficult to debug, if you also try to use `sum` as a function.

Here's a working version (note also a better code style):

```
function res = trapez(a, b, k)
    res = 0;
    h = (b-a)/k; % split up the interval in equidistant spaces

    for j = 1:k
        x_j1 = a + (j-1)*h;
        x_j = a + j*h;  % this are the points in the interval
        res = res+ ((x_j - x_j1)/2) * (integrand(x_j1) + integrand(x_j));
    end
end

function y = integrand(x)
    y = x*exp(-x^2); % This will be integrand I want to approximate
end
```

And the way to call it is: `result = trapez(0, 1, 10);`

Comment: +1, however, "But in this case there's no need to pass it at all." is only true if `integrand` is on the path, otherwise it just happens to be a call to a function handle passed in – it's a bad idea to use a argument with the same name.

Comment: Overriding the common built in function `sum` as a variable name is also bad practice.

Comment: Thanks. What name should I give to the file?

Comment: @horchler thanks, added a note on `sum` to the answer. @kamil, if you place both functions in the same file, you should make `trapez` the main function and name the file accordingly, as this is what you'll be calling. `integrand` in this case would be a local function. Alternatively you could place each function in its own file.

Answer (score 0):

Your `integrand`function requires an input argument `x`, which you are not supplying in your command line function call

Comment: I just tried that. I get the error 'Undefined function or variable 'x'.' ?

Comment: I think the problem is with the integrand function. If I want to run it, it always says x is undefined. I don't understand